# While creating new android project,asking fragment layout name.

Tags: android

Whenever i am creating new android application in step4 it is asking fragment layout name.But  i dont want to create any fragment as i am basic android learner.Can anybody suggest how to remove that option from the screen?

Comment: I don't know how to remove that from the new Activity wizard, but you could just delete the fragment xml and associated code and continue as usual.

Comment: doesnt let u create an activity...